# Trouble creating horizontal automatic scrolling textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

I'm trying to create an automatic scrolling textblock.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="400">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" />

    <StackPanel x:Name="UserContainer" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="UserStatusLabel" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="nl-nl" Text="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit."/>
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
              <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                From="{Binding ElementName=UserContainer, Path=Width}" To="-200"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="translate"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                Duration="0:0:3"
                                AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Background="Blue" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

But I have 3 problems:

- The text should be scrolled to the left till the end. Now it stops at a certain point
- The text should not cross the red container at the left, it shouldn't run trough it.
- The text is cut off at a certain point, but I don't know why.

Comment: Your textblock is 'cut off' because your textbox's width is limited by it's parent stackpanel's width. I would try to put the TextBlock inside a Canvas (which doesn't adjust its width to its parent container)

Comment: I also don't understand why you have the "From" property of you animation set to UserContainer.Width instead of just 0..

Comment: Also, it doesn't scroll until the end because of the '-200' which I think should be adjusted to - (minus) UserStatusLabel.ActualWidth (you can use a converter for the minus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add `ClipToBounds="True"` to you central `StackPanel` to stop the text from showing after it leaves the bounds of the `StackPanel`.

Secondly, the text stops at a 'certain distance' as you say because you told it to by setting the `DoubleAnimation` to only move to `-200`. We need to replace that with the actual value of the `StackPanel.ActualWidth` property:

```
<DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UserContainer}" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="translate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:3" 
    AutoReverse="True" />
```

However, this moves the text to the right edge instead. I'm going to give this to you as an answer for now and if I can think of an easy way to reverse the direction of movement, I'll come back and edit it later.

UPADTE >>>

Ok, so the easiest thing to make the text move left is to implement a simple `Converter`:

```
public class AdditiveInverseDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(double) && targetType != typeof(double)) return false;
        return -(double)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(double) && targetType != typeof(double)) return false;
        return -(double)value;
    }
}
```

Then change your XAML:

```
<DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UserContainer, Converter={
    StaticResource AdditiveInverseDoubleConverter}}" Storyboard.TargetName="translate" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:3" AutoReverse="True" />
```

Don't forget to add the XML Namespace:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
```

And `Resource`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:AdditiveInverseDoubleConverter x:Key="AdditiveInverseDoubleConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

UPDATE 2 >>>

Ah, I just worked it out... the `TextBlock` is cut off because it won't fit into the `StackPanel` otherwise... making the `StackPanel` bigger makes more text appear. However, the answer is to not use the `StackPanel` and use a `Canvas` instead... this shows *all* of the text.

Comment: The text is cut off because of the textbox's width, not because he moves only to -200..

Comment: Thanks @franssu, I didn't spot that error, although it's not the length of the `TextBlock` either... it is still cut off with a large `Width` set.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that with Render Transform you are transforming only what has been rendered, and your text has been cut at that point.
LayoutTransform ignores TranslateTransform, so you cant use it here, but if you were using RotateTransform  you would see the rest of the text appearing.
Not sure how you can achieve your goal with Render Transform.

```
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform  x:Name="translate" />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation
                            From="0" To="90"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="translate"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            Duration="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
```

Edit:
What about Margin animation, its working fine:

```
<ThicknessAnimation
     Storyboard.TargetName="UserStatusLabel"
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
     Duration="0:0:3" AutoReverse="True"  From="0,0,0,0" To="-200,0,0,0" />
```